# How to select a matrix of distinct values in PL/SQL using “where” expression for each cell

Tags: sql, select, plsql, group-by, plsqldeveloper

I’m interested to analyze a table in Oracle which has the following form:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 0 | A |
| 14 | 1 | 7 |
| 45 | 3 | 3 |
| 64 | 3 | 3 |
| 80 | 7 | 3 |

IMPORTANT:
Column A is varchar2(10)
Column B is Number(1)
Column C is Char(1)

```
A is primary key 
B has only {0,1,3,7} distinct   values
C has only {‘0’,’1’,’2’,’3’,’4’,’5’,’6’,’7’,’8’,’9’,’A’} distinct values
```

I want to make select command that will show matrix of distinct values where each cell will be result of expression such as

```
select count(*) from table where  B = 1 and C = ‘A’
```

It means that we will get this kind of matrix:

|  | 0 | 1 | 3 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |
| 8 |  |  |  |  |
| 9 |  |  |  |  |
| A |  |  |  |  |

For example cell(B = 3, C = ‘A’) will contain result of this command:

```
select count(*) from table where  B = 3 and C = ‘A’
```

Is it possible to make this only with select command or I need to create new tables and make scripts?

I have tried to make it manually with this command

```
select count(*) from table where  B = 1 and C = ‘A’
```

Just alter B and C values in this command myself and it makes me tired because it takes a lot of time. This table is enormous for this king of commands. So, I’m interested to use universal command that helps me to analyze this table

Comment: Please actually fill in the matriz with the results you require from the example data. *(Are the result Columns always going to be the same? Or would you want them to change with the data?)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create additional table (or subquery or temporal table) for holding the rows:

```
CREATE TABLE subquery (col Char(1));

INSERT INTO subquery(col) VALUES ('0');
INSERT INTO subquery(col) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO subquery(col) VALUES ('2');
INSERT INTO subquery(col) VALUES ('3');
INSERT INTO subquery(col) VALUES ('4');
INSERT INTO subquery(col) VALUES ('5');
INSERT INTO subquery(col) VALUES ('6');
INSERT INTO subquery(col) VALUES ('7');
INSERT INTO subquery(col) VALUES ('8');
INSERT INTO subquery(col) VALUES ('9');
INSERT INTO subquery(col) VALUES ('A');
```

Then, simply write:

```
SELECT A.col
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN B.Column_B = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Col0
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN B.Column_B = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Col1
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN B.Column_B = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Col3
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN B.Column_B = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Col7
FROM subquery A
LEFT JOIN example_table B
  ON A.col = B.Column_C
GROUP BY A.col
ORDER BY A.col
```

[image]

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7affeb/8) is the full working example.

Answer (score 0):

I found it simple:

```
SELECT B,C, count(*) from table group by B,C
```

It will not show matrix, but this vector can be used to create matrix by using B and C values as indexes and count(*) as value